# eval bash function arguments without misescaping

Tags: bash

In a Bash script, I want to create a function that wraps commands, printing them before executing them.

So, in a script command like this:

```
mkdir -p "~/new/dir/tree/"
rsync -e 'ssh -p 22' -av "src/" "user@${HOST}:dest/"
```

I could put a command in front of the others like this:

```
run mkdir -p "~/new/dir/tree/"
run rsync -e 'ssh -p 22' -av "src/" "user@${HOST}:dest/"
```

I define the function run as:

```
run (){
    echo -e "FANCY FORMATING CMD> $@ FANCY FORMAT ENDING"
    eval "$@"
    return $?
}
```

It works fine for most cases. When I need the command in front of `run` it should work with it or without it whether you remove the `run` part or unset the `run`. I mean, all three commands should work exactly the same way:

```
run original_comand arg1 "arg2 subarg2" etc;
unset run;
run original_comand arg1 "arg2 subarg2" etc;
original_comand arg1 "arg2 subarg2" etc;
```

But if I try with this line:

```
run rsync -e 'ssh -p 22' -av "src/" "user@${HOST}:dest/"
```

the `-e` argument became unquoted and the command actually run is

```
run rsync -e ssh -p 22 -av src/ user@${HOST}:dest/
```

If I escape the quote on the `-e` argument, it may work with the run command, but it would not work without it.

As far as I could read from Bash documentation, the `"$@"` should work, but clearly I'm missing something here.

Comment: why don't you use bash -x ./your_script.sh ?

Comment: Indeed, along with `PS4='$(FANCY FORMATTING CMD)'`, `set -x` provides a very nice solution.  Trying to correctly quote things like this is notoriously difficult.

Comment: Instead of `eval "$@"` you should do `"$@"` without the `eval`. It will execute the command in `"$1"` and pass it the arguments `"${@:2}"`.

Comment: Notice that `mkdir "~/..."` would create a subdirectory called `~` in the current directory (tilde not expanded in quotes). Use `$HOME` instead.

Comment: @Robin479 Using "$@" instead of eval "$@" seems to be the right solution for me by now. I'll test it for a while to check it. Thanks

Comment: @Robin479 You may want to create an answer with the tip you gave me in the comments here, so I can give you the proper credits for the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments you pass to `run` already underwent all sorts of expansion when they were passed to run, and are also already properly positioned, so you don't need `eval` to invoke the command in `$1`. In fact, it is an error to use `eval` in this case (which erroneously applies expansions and word-splitting of sorts yet another time) as you can tell by the plenty error messages you get.

The proper way to invoke the command in `$1` and passing it all the arguments in `"$@"` (except for the first, i.e. `"${@:2}"`), is to simply put `"$@"` on a single line without `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments are not "unquoted" by calling your function.  They are "unquoted" by putting them in a string and echoing it. The quotes are not part of the arguments, but special characters in the shell that prevents word-splitting (and in the case of single quotes, variable expansion).

The shell does word-splitting (which quotes protect against), then quote removal. This means that the quotes would be removed, yes, but that the arguments would not be split on quoted whitespace.

In

```
utility a "b c"
```

the utility would not get `"b c"` as its second argument, but `b c` (not `b` and `c`, but `b<space>c`).  The same goes for your function.

This shows that you still get properly separated arguments in the function:

```
#!/bin/sh

run () {
    printf 'Arg: %s\n' "$@"
}

HOST=example.com

run mkdir -p "~/new/dir/tree/"
echo '---'
run rsync -e 'ssh -p 22' -av "src/" "user@${HOST}:dest/"
```

This generates

```
Arg: mkdir
Arg: -p
Arg: ~/new/dir/tree/
---
Arg: rsync
Arg: -e
Arg: ssh -p 22
Arg: -av
Arg: src/
Arg: user@example.com:dest/
```

As you can see, `ssh -p 22` is still delivered to `printf` as a separate argument, not three arguments.

Doing `eval "$@"` in your function will do the right thing.  Escaping the quotes would definitely *not* do the right thing as it would include the quotes in the actual argument (`mkdir \"dir\"` would create a directory called `"dir"`, including the quotes, and `rsync -e \"ssh -p 22\"` would be delivered to `rsync` as `-e`, `"ssh`, `-p`, `22"`).

Also, note that `~` is not expanded since it was in double quotes. Use `$HOME` instead.